# even after putting FS as comma awk is considerins space as well for FS

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have set FS for awk as FS = "," but it is still using space as delimiter. After using below code it has created 3 array elemnets, one for commma and other for space. Please suggest how can I restrict awk to not use space as FS

Code :

```
arr_values=(`awk  'BEGIN{FS = ","} 
                        {for (i=0; i<=NF; i++)
                           print $i
                        }; 
                   END{}' File`)
for ((i=0; i<${#arr_values[@]}; i++))
do
  echo ${arr_values[$i]}
done
```

content of File :

```
1, abc def
```

Output :

```
abc
def
1
abc
def
```

Comment: Awk is not using space as a delimiter, I promise you. Isolate just the awk part and you'll see. Not sure if you mean to start your for loop with `0` --- awk is printing `$0`, `$1`, and `$2` in that case (`$0` is the entire line). Can you show your expected output?

Comment: There nothing specific about autput. What I really need is two array elements
element1 = 1
element2 = abc def

Answer (score 3):

First, [quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes#When_Should_You_Quote.3F) should be surrounding [command substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst) to prevent unwanted word splitting.  When command output expands into an array unquoted, each whitespace delimited field gets separated into its own element.

Also, as jas mentioned, the Awk loop should be initializing `i` to `1` not `0`.  The `$0` record in Awk is the entire line, which is why the array contains duplicates.

However, quoting variables won't do what you want:

```
$ arr_values=("$(awk -F', ' '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print $i}' File)")
$ echo "${arr_values[0]}"
1
abc def
```

The newline is preserved here but is all contained a single element of the array because the quotes enclose the entire command substitution output.

To accomplish what you want, use the [Bash builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html) `readarray`.  It will read each line from standard input into a separate array element:

```
$ readarray -t arr_values < <(awk -F', ' '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print $i}' File)
$ for ((i=0; i<${#arr_values[@]}; i++)); do echo "${arr_values[$i]}"; done
1
abc def
```

[See demo](https://ideone.com/3NBnGq)

Comment: Thanks John for answer, but there is something wrong with the array assignment. Its basically generating array with only one element which is

Comment: Thanks John for answer, but there is something wrong with the array assignment. Its basically generating array with only one element which is 1 followed by abc def in next line. I tried initializing a variable and incrementing after looping but it was never incremented. I need two elements in array.

Comment: @him I see, I may have misunderstood your original intention.  I think `readarray` is the best tool for the job.  Please see updated answer.

Comment: I think you correctly understood the original intention, but the output that your code is generating is partially correct, I mean it is giving output in two lines but it is actually only one element displayed in two lines. How can we further break it into two array elements

Comment: @him Yes, the original question was asking about Awk `FS`.  Please read the update and try the suggestion using `readarray` which assigns each line to a different element.